# What’s the difference between 1人のお客さん and お客さんの1人？

Tags: grammar, counters

Does one have a different meaning? My guess is that 1人のお客さん means "one guest", while お客さんの1人 means "one of the guests", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your guess is correct.